# Proving that a sequence is Cauchy

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing, solution-verification

Show that if $\{a_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence of reals, then $\{a_n^2\}$ is a Cauchy sequence (for $n \geq 1$).

My attempt:

From previous theorem, a sequence of reals is Cauchy $\iff$ the sequence converges.

Let $a = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. Notice that $\{a_n\}$ converges; so $\{a_n\}$ is bounded. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $L > 0$ s.t. $|a_n| \leq L$ for all $n \geq 1$. We have that there exists $n' \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $|a_n - a| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2L}$ for all $n \geq n'$. For $n \geq n'$

$$|a_n^2 - a^2| = |a_n - a||a_n + a|$$

By triangle inequality, $|a_n + a| \leq |a_n| + |a|$ and as $|a_n| \leq L$, we have that $|a_n| + |a| \leq L + L = 2L$. Hence for $n \geq n'$

$$|a_n - a||a_n + a| < \frac{\epsilon}{2L} \cdot 2L = \epsilon$$

Thus, $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n^2 = a^2$ and we may conclude that the sequence is Cauchy.

Is this proof correct? Also, would using the rule that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n) = a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} (b_n) = b \implies \lim_{n\to\infty} (a_nb_n) = ab$ be a valid proof here?

Comment: Convergence of the sequence implies convergence of the squares, because continuity of the square function. So directly, you get that it's Cauchy

Comment: Yes, your argument is correct, and the answer to your last question is also *yes*.

Comment: Cannot you just note that Cauchy sequences are bounded too and use the same argument with $|a_n^2 - a_m^2| = |a_n - a_m||a_n + a_m|$ instead? That way you keep it "pure"; the result is provable without knowing the sequence converges in the reals.